# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on string

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

wait please, dont post this as a duplicate because ive done research and tried everything but cant get it to work, i keep getting this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\wamp64\www\Etego\dbcontroller.php on line 63" i am trying to get people on my inscription form not to use the same email twice, thanks in advance! heres the code :

dbcontroller.php

```
<?php
class DBController {
    public $host = "localhost";
    public $user = "root";
    public $password = "";
    public $database = "members";
    public $conn;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
    }

    function connectDB() {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
        return $conn;
    }

    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }        
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }

    function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;    
    }

    function updateQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query1: ' . mysqli_error($this->conn));
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    function insertQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query2: ' . mysqli_error($this->conn));
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    function deleteQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query3: ' . mysqli_error($this->conn));
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}


/* Email already exists */
/*line 63*/       
$db = new DBController; 
$db->database->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = ?");
$reqemail->execute(array($email));
$emailexist = $reqemail->rowCount();
if($emailexist == 0) {
} else {
    $error_message = "Email already exists";
}
//end of email existance
?>
```

index2.php

```
<!-- how to make members when login "keep me signed in"  and ho to make users 13+ with the date input -->

<?php
if(!empty($_POST["register-user"])) {
    /* Form Required Field Validation */
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if(empty($_POST[$key])) {
        $error_message = "All Fields are required";
        break;
        }
    }
    /* Password Matching Validation */
    if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']){ 
    $error_message = 'Passwords should be same<br>'; 
    }

    /* Email Validation */
    if(!isset($error_message)) {
        if (!filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error_message = "Invalid Email Address";
        }
    }

    /* Validation to check if gender is selected */
    if(!isset($error_message)) {
    if(!isset($_POST["gender"])) {
    $error_message = " All Fields are required";
    }
    }

    /* Validation to check if Terms and Conditions are accepted */
    if(!isset($error_message)) {
        if(!isset($_POST["terms"])) {
        $error_message = "Accept Terms and Conditions to Register";
        }
    }





    if(!isset($error_message)) {
        require_once("dbcontroller.php");
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "INSERT INTO members (username, firstname, lastname, password, email, gender, dob) VALUES
        ('" . $_POST["userName"] . "', '" . $_POST["firstName"] . "', '" . $_POST["lastName"] . "', '" . md5($_POST["password"]) . "', '" . $_POST["userEmail"] . "', '" . $_POST["gender"] . "' , '" . $_POST["dob"] . "' )";
        $result = $db_handle->insertQuery($query);
        if(!empty($result)) {
            $error_message = "";
            $success_message = "You have registered successfully!";    
            unset($_POST);
        } else {
            $error_message = "Problem in registration. Try Again!";    
        }
    }
}
?>
<html>

<?php 


    include 'C:\wamp64\www\Etego\stylesignup.css';


    ?>


<head>
<title>https://Etego/signup.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmRegistration" method="post" action="">
<table border="0" width="500" align="center" class="demo-table">
<?php if(!empty($success_message)) { ?>    
<div class="success-message"><?php if(isset($success_message)) echo $success_message; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if(!empty($error_message)) { ?>    
<div class="error-message"><?php if(isset($error_message)) echo $error_message; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
<td>User Name</td>
<td><input type="text" class="demoInputBox allinsc" name="userName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['userName'])) echo $_POST['userName']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td><input type="text" class="demoInputBox allinsc" name="firstName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['firstName'])) echo $_POST['firstName']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td><input type="text" class="demoInputBox allinsc" name="lastName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['lastName'])) echo $_POST['lastName']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td><input type="password" class="demoInputBox allinsc" name="password" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Confirm Password</td>
<td><input type="password" class="demoInputBox allinsc" name="confirm_password" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td><input type="text" class="demoInputBox allinsc" name="userEmail" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['userEmail'])) echo $_POST['userEmail']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
<td>Date Of birth</td>
<td><input type="date" value="<?php print(date("YYYY-MM-DD"))?>" class="demoInputBox" name="dob" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['dob'])) echo $_POST['dob']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" <?php if(isset($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender']=="Male") { ?>checked<?php  } ?>> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" <?php if(isset($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender']=="Female") { ?>checked<?php  } ?>> Female
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="not specified" <?php if(isset($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender']=="not specified") { ?>checked<?php  } ?>> not specified
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>
<input type="checkbox" name="terms"> I accept <a href="terms.html">Terms and Conditions</a> <input type="submit" name="register-user" value="Register" class="btnRegister"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>

<div class="header1"></div>
    <div class="hdetail1"></div>

    <h class="etegotxt1">Etego</h>

    <img src="Etego_Logo.png" alt="Etego logo" width="50" height="50" class="logo1">

</body></html>
```

Comment: So, `$db->database`  IS  a string!  (set to members)   Try to `$db->prepare(...)` instead.

Comment: @PaulT. Fatal error: Call to undefined method DBController::prepare()

Comment: You have it a bit different than I would have expected, then try: `$db->conn->prepare(...)` Looks like @sazzadur has already answered.

Comment: any idea how maybe i could transfer that ito my index2.php instead of on dbcontroller because all my other error_messages are on index2

Comment: You dont want to include like this `include 'C:\wamp64\www\Etego\stylesignup.css';` as when you move your site specially to a unix server that wond work. Use reletive paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues here:

Where you are trying to prepare a statement you are using `$db->database->prepare()` and if you look at your class the propery `database` it is a String containing the string `members` i.e. `public $database = "members";` *Which explains the error that is being reported*

You also appear to have got the `mysqli_` API and the `PDO` API confused and are using some PDO API functions, *that will never work they are totally different beasts*.

So also change this

```
/* Email already exists */
/*line 63*/       
$db = new DBController; 
$db->database->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = ?");
$reqemail->execute(array($email));
$emailexist = $reqemail->rowCount();
if($emailexist == 0) {
} else {
    $error_message = "Email already exists";
}
```

To

```
/* Email already exists */
/*line 63*/       
$db = new DBController; 
$stmt = $db->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $error_message = "Email already exists";
}
```

and you will be using the connection object to prepare the query and all `mysqli_` API functions, methods and properties.

UPDATE: Still getting dup accounts created

Your dup account check is in the wrong place in my opinion and should be moved into the index2.php.

Or after this line add a test against `$error_message` because you are forgetting to test if the Dup email check produced an error.

```
if(!isset($error_message)) {
    require_once("dbcontroller.php");
    if ( !isset($error_message) ) {
```

My strong suggestion would be to do the Dup Email check in index2 and remove it from `dbconnect.php` as it does not really belong in `dbconnect.php` as that would be run unnecessarily everytime you want to connect to a database in any script!

Comment: Totally different beasts indeed. That blew me away, shiver me timber.

Comment: great everything seems to work but i can still use the same email for different accounts and it says that ill be registered.

Comment: Well that rather depends upon what you do after this code and in code you have not shown us. So I suggest you ask another question about that

Comment: @RiggsFolly ive shown you all the code i have and plus ill have to wait like 2 days to ask another question so id love if you could maybe do it now? of course its only if you want to.

Comment: THere you go, fix suggested

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'DBController' not found @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1):

The thing is your `$database` variable is a string that does not have `prepare()` function. Instead you might want to use the `$conn` variable that is holding a valid database connection.

To do that, change

```
$db->database->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = ?");
```

to

```
$stmt = $db->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

Here is the PHP [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.prepare.html).